# Laravel: Allow single user login per session

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpmyadmin, laravel-blade

So i have three user types **User, Admin and Recruiter**. When the User login with m**iddleware "web"** an Admin or recruiter user can also login base on a link selected.

How can I log out the current user or show a message that another user type is logged in.

The thing is, I want to allow admin or recruiter to still see a login link but not login when a current user is already logged in.

Comment: You could use the guest middleware for your login routes.

Comment: How would the guest middleware solve this problem? Wouldn't it only allow anyone to login from there?

Comment: guest middleware is the opposite of auth middleware. It only allows those that aren't logged in to do so.